# Simple math calculations with js and html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 2 problems here in the fiddle example. First, when you click checkboxes it should do the calculation instantly but it doesn't. You just have to first change the dropbox value, then check values and then it works. Does anyone knows what to do to get the result right after choosing values from checkboxes? I need the standard option to be selected by default.
Second thing is I need to get the result from the same values but smaller of 10% and 20%.

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.sum')
var select = document.querySelector('#select')
var total = document.querySelector('#payment-total,#payment-total-2')
var checkboxesTotal = 0
var selectTotal = 0

checkboxes.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('change', onCheckboxSelect)
})

select.addEventListener('change', onSelectChange)

function onCheckboxSelect(e) {
  var sign = e.target.checked ? 1 : -1
  checkboxesTotal += sign * parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
  renderTotal()
}

function onSelectChange(e) {
  var value = parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    selectTotal = value
    renderTotal()
  }
}

function renderTotal() {
  total.innerHTML = checkboxesTotal * selectTotal
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><label class="checkbox" for="Checkbox1">
    <input value="190" type="checkbox" class="sum"> Value 1
    </label></li>
  <li><label class="checkbox">
    <input value="190" type="checkbox" class="sum"> Value 2
    </label></li>
  <li><label class="checkbox">
    <input value="170" type="checkbox" class="sum"> Value 3
    </label></li>
</ul>
<br/>
<br/>
<select id="select" name="select">
  <option value="1" class="sum">Basic</option>
  <option value="2" class="sum" selected="selected">Standard</option>
  <option value="3" class="sum">Premium</option>
</select>
<br/>
<p>3 months <br>sum: <span id="payment-total">0</span> ;- month.</p>
<p>6 months (10% off) <br>sum: <span id="payment-total-2">0</span> ;- month.</p>
<p>12 months (20% off) <br>sum: <span id="payment-total-3">0</span> ;- month.</p>
```

Comment: The `change` event occurs only when you leave the control. You likely want the `click` event. Also, don't use `for` on a `label` unless there's a form element with an ID that matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your checkboxes is that you are setting the initial value of `var selectTotal = 0` and when checking one checkbox, the calculation is made with `selectTotal = 0`, meaning that `total3.innerHTML = checkboxesTotal * selectTotal = 190 * 0 = 0` (for first checkbox checked).
You can change it by initializing `selectTotal` to your default value, which is `2` (Standard) or when checking the checkbox, you can get the selected value from the dropdown.

The first approach is with `var selectTotal = 2`:

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.sum')
var select = document.querySelector('#select')
var total3 = document.querySelector('#payment-total')
var total6 = document.querySelector('#payment-total2')
var total12 = document.querySelector('#payment-total3')
var checkboxesTotal = 0;
var selectTotal = 2; // Standard (default dropdown value)

checkboxes.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('change', onCheckboxSelect)
})

select.addEventListener('click', onSelectChange)

function onCheckboxSelect(e) {
  var sign = e.target.checked ? 1 : -1
  checkboxesTotal += sign * parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
  renderTotal()
}

function onSelectChange(e) {
  var value = parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    selectTotal = value
    renderTotal()
  }
}

function renderTotal() {
  total3.innerHTML = checkboxesTotal * selectTotal
  total6.innerHTML = (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal / 100) * (-10) + (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal)
  total12.innerHTML = (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal / 100) * (-20) + (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal)
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><label class="checkbox">
    <input value="190" type="checkbox" class="sum"> Wadowice
</label></li>
<li><label class="checkbox">
    <input value="190" type="checkbox" class="sum"> Kalwaria
  </label></li>
  <li><label class="checkbox">
    <input value="170" type="checkbox" class="sum"> Zator
  </label></li>
</ul>

<br/>
<br/>

<select id="select" name="select">
    <option value="1" class="sum">Basic</option>
    <option value="2" class="sum" selected="selected">Standard</option>
    <option value="3" class="sum">Premium</option>
  
</select>


<br/>
<p>
3 months <br>sum: <span id="payment-total">0</span> ;- month.
</p>

<p>
6 months <br>sum: <span id="payment-total2">0</span> ;- month.
</p>

<p>
12 months <br>sum: <span id="payment-total3">0</span> ;- month.
</p>
```

The second approach is with getting dropdown value when making selection of checkbox:

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.sum')
var select = document.querySelector('#select')
var total3 = document.querySelector('#payment-total')
var total6 = document.querySelector('#payment-total2')
var total12 = document.querySelector('#payment-total3')
var checkboxesTotal = 0;
var selectTotal = 0;

checkboxes.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('change', onCheckboxSelect)
})

select.addEventListener('click', onSelectChange)

function onCheckboxSelect(e) {
  var sign = e.target.checked ? 1 : -1
  checkboxesTotal += sign * parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
  var select = document.getElementById("select");
  // get selected value and assign it to the global variable selectTotal
  selectTotal = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  renderTotal()
}

function onSelectChange(e) {
  var value = parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    selectTotal = value
    renderTotal()
  }
}

function renderTotal() {
  total3.innerHTML = checkboxesTotal * selectTotal
  total6.innerHTML = (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal / 100) * (-10) + (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal)
  total12.innerHTML = (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal / 100) * (-20) + (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal)
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><label class="checkbox">
    <input value="190" type="checkbox" class="sum"> Wadowice
</label></li>
<li><label class="checkbox">
    <input value="190" type="checkbox" class="sum"> Kalwaria
  </label></li>
  <li><label class="checkbox">
    <input value="170" type="checkbox" class="sum"> Zator
  </label></li>
</ul>

<br/>
<br/>

<select id="select" name="select">
    <option value="1" class="sum">Basic</option>
    <option value="2" class="sum" selected="selected">Standard</option>
    <option value="3" class="sum">Premium</option>
  
</select>


<br/>
<p>
3 months <br>sum: <span id="payment-total">0</span> ;- month.
</p>

<p>
6 months <br>sum: <span id="payment-total2">0</span> ;- month.
</p>

<p>
12 months <br>sum: <span id="payment-total3">0</span> ;- month.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the solution for percentage problem, now it does the desired job. But still trying to figure out the checkboxes. They still don't' respond until you click on the dropdown. Thanks in advance!

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.sum')
var select = document.querySelector('#select')
var total3 = document.querySelector('#payment-total')
var total6 = document.querySelector('#payment-total2')
var total12 = document.querySelector('#payment-total3')
var checkboxesTotal = 0
var selectTotal = 0

checkboxes.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('change', onCheckboxSelect)
})

select.addEventListener('click', onSelectChange)

function onCheckboxSelect(e) {
  var sign = e.target.checked ? 1 : -1
  checkboxesTotal += sign * parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
  renderTotal()
}

function onSelectChange(e) {
  var value = parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    selectTotal = value
    renderTotal()
  }
}

function renderTotal() {
  total3.innerHTML = checkboxesTotal * selectTotal
  total6.innerHTML = (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal / 100) * (-10) + (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal)
  total12.innerHTML = (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal / 100) * (-20) + (checkboxesTotal * selectTotal)
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><label class="checkbox">
    <input value="190" type="checkbox" class="sum"> Wadowice
</label></li>
<li><label class="checkbox">
    <input value="190" type="checkbox" class="sum"> Kalwaria
  </label></li>
  <li><label class="checkbox">
    <input value="170" type="checkbox" class="sum"> Zator
  </label></li>
</ul>

<br/>
<br/>

<select id="select" name="select">
    <option value="1" class="sum">Basic</option>
    <option value="2" class="sum" selected="selected">Standard</option>
    <option value="3" class="sum">Premium</option>
  
</select>


<br/>
<p>
3 months <br>sum: <span id="payment-total">0</span> ;- month.
</p>

<p>
6 months <br>sum: <span id="payment-total2">0</span> ;- month.
</p>

<p>
12 months <br>sum: <span id="payment-total3">0</span> ;- month.
</p>
```